# Move windows to the top of the screen in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, aero

I have some windows that use up a bunch of horizontal space on my monitor. Prior to Windows 7, I could drag the window to the very top so that there would be only a sliver of the title bar remaining.

With Windows 7, every time I try to put some of the title bar above the top of the screen, it will automatically shift it downwards, or it will have the annoying "full-screen" effect.

Is there any way to disable these two behaviors?

Answer (score 6):

You're referring to "Aero Snap". Our very own how-to geek has an article on disabling it [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/disable-the-mouse-drag-window-arranging-feature-in-windows-7/).

Comment: Lol John, sometimes your just annoyingly fast ;-)

Comment: actually fairly slow this time, 5 minutes.

Comment: You really are fast!

Comment: Thanks this helps, but unfortunately it still shifts the window downwards when I try to move the Title Bar off the top of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

You dislike the new Aero Snap feature. Here's a [My Digital Life tutorial](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/05/20/disable-aero-snap-auto-maximize-and-arrange-window-in-windows-7/) on turning it off. Or an [alternative registry hack](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/07/22/how-to-disable-or-enable-turn-on-or-off-windows-7-snap-automatically-maximize-and-arrange-window/) (same source)

> Aero Snap is definitely a welcoming
>   feature to many users who need to
>   quickly maximize or half-maximize
>   windows for viewing or comparison.
>   However, some Windows 7 users may have
>   different need or usage behavior, such
>   as those need always drag a window to
>   the edge of the desktop to work on
>   other tasks, or just need to monitor
>   and look at the some tiny corner part
>   of the window. In Windows 7 system
>   with multiple monitors, Aero Snap auto
>   adjustment of window may go erroneous
>   too, where the maximized window may
>   span across multiple monitors, making
>   it harder to read.

Use the trick below to disable and turn off Aero Snap ability to auto arrange or auto maximize window when dragging.

- Go to Control Panel.
- Click on Ease of Access link or Ease of Access Center icon.
- Select Change how your mouse works or Make the mouse easier to use option.
- Tick the check box for Prevent Windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen with the mouse under “Make it easier to manage windows” section.

  [image]
- Click OK or Apply to make the change effective.

Once Aero Snap is disabled, the window won’t be automatically maximized and arranged when window is dragged to the edge of the screen, including both top and sides of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a workaround (can't test it as I'm not on Windows 7 at this time):

- click on the system menu in the upper left corner of the window
- select "move"
- now use the up arrow (on the keyboard) to move the window until the title bar is above the visual part of the screen
- press <kbd>enter</kbd> to stop moving

Comment: This does not work. Upon pressing enter the window moves back

Answer (score 0):

You can disable Aero snap by clicking start then starting to type "ease of access" and click on it when you see it (or go to control panel and open "ease of access")

After this, click "Make the mouse easier to use" and tick "Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen".

Answer (score 0):

Use the trick below to disable and turn off Aero Snap ability to auto arrange or auto maximize window when dragging.

Go to **Control Panel** 
Click on **Ease of Access** link or **Ease of Access Center** icon.
Select **Change how your mouse works** or **Make the mouse easier to use** option.
Tick the check box for **Prevent Windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen** with the mouse under “Make it easier to manage windows” section.

You can see the infoemation in here http://www.mydigitallife.info/disable-aero-snap-auto-maximize-and-arrange-window-in-windows-7/